# How do you make a custom scroll bar?

Tags: html, css, web, scrollbar

Can anyone give a thorough explanation of how to make custom scroll bars? Are custom scroll bars compatible with all browsers?

Comment: Only WebKit supports "custom" scrollbars through CSS. For a cross-browser solution, you need to use JavaScript to make a fake scrollbar.

Comment: Consider this: http://www.palmantics.com/html/scrollbars/

Comment: I added the output of the above link to my css and it didn't work...

Comment: "....these properties has been dropped since Internet Explorer 6, so they are no longer applicable today."

Answer (score 1):

You need to use pure **javaScript** to become compatible with all browsers.

This is one of the best solution for that

http://www.script-tutorials.com/custom-scrollbars-cross-browser-solution/

Answer (score 0):

These were one search away, and they're really good:

http://codemug.com/html/custom-scrollbars-using-css/

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-scroll-bar/

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/674478/Customize-Scrollbars-using-CSS3

Answer (score 0):

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      background-color: #eaeaea;
      border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Simply add the above.